# Samsung Tab A 9.7"

Tags: samsung, tablet

I just got a Samsung Tab A. I don't always get a full screen when watching TV. Is this normal with this model?

Comment: I'll shift the comment to a formal answer; kindly accept if it's indeed on point, or comment on the answer if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

The content provided may simply not have the same aspect ratio as your screen (4:3), so you get black edges. One reason why 4:3 tablets are bad for media consumption.

Comment: Remark: listening to audio ***media*** the aspect ratio is irrelevant. Most photos are done using the "golden ratio" as well, plus there are many movies in 4:3 – so saying the ratio is "bad for media consumption" is a bit too generalizing; one could say the same for 16:9 tablets when referring to those 4:3 movies or watching photos/slide-shows (black bars left and right) ;)

Comment: @Izzy Uh, really, tablets for music? Also movies are even shifting towards 21:9 by now, so the good'ol Iconia Smart might not be a bad idea to rework on. The photo part is right - I should indeed have made the claim more clearly restricted to motion picture, but I'll leave it as it is and let the comments fill in.

Comment: Why not? Also, there're always [DLNA / uPnP Server and Clients](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna) :) And yes, that's basically what I've meant: "media" was the wrong term (don't forget the "print media" in electronic form, e.g. eBooks and also websites). But maybe I'm splitting hairs here ;)

Comment: @Izzy That's a pricey and not-so-portable slab you got for music enjoyment... About the Ebook part, now that you mentioned it, nobody actually refers to Ebooks when they talk about "media consumption" around our part, they usually reserve a separate mention for it.